# Mysql DELETE ON CASCADE won't work

Tags: mysql, sql, parent-child, cascade, sql-delete

Hello Stackoverflow people

I have a parent table called

- character_,

and two child table called:

- Learned_Skills
- Learned_Talents

What i am trying to achieve is when i delete a person from Character_, it also deletes all informations from the tables Learned_skills and Learned_Talents.
I am aware that a ON DELETE CASCADE is required, however, when i try to delete a person, it does not delete its information on the child tables, what am i doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE character_ ( 
  Name_             varchar (30) NOT NULL,
  Class             varchar (30),
  World_Type        varchar (15),
  Str               integer     ,
  WS                integer     ,               
  BS                integer     ,
  Fel               integer     ,
  Per               integer     ,
  Int_              integer     ,
  Agi               integer     ,
  WP                integer     ,
  Tough             integer     ,  
  PRIMARY KEY (Name_)           ,
  FOREIGN KEY (Class) REFERENCES Class(Class_name),
  FOREIGN KEY (World_Type) REFERENCES World_Type(Name_)     );


 CREATE TABLE Learned_Talents ( 
  Character_Name    varchar (30) NOT NULL,
  Talent_Name       varchar (40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Character_Name,Talent_Name),
  FOREIGN KEY (Character_Name) REFERENCES character_(Name_) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (Talent_Name) REFERENCES Talents(TalentName)  );


  CREATE TABLE Learned_Skills ( 
  Character_Name    varchar (30) NOT NULL,
  Skill_Name        varchar (40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Character_Name,Skill_Name),
  FOREIGN KEY (Character_Name) REFERENCES character_(Name_) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (Skill_Name) REFERENCES Skills(SkillName) );
```

Comment: @PaulZ meaning i cant have more than one ON DELETE CASCADE, is that what you mean?

Comment: No. Check the linked question, which is exactly the same problem as yours. Your problem is that you're using MyISAM, which does not support foreign keys at all. Use `ENGINE=InnoDB` when defining your tables.

Comment: so by adding ENGINE=InnoDB after the ); it should work? @PaulZ